Ubuntu 24.04 random stuttering and freezing although on a powerful machine
I just came to Ubuntu new and deleted all my Windows devices. I made a clear installation of Ubuntu's latest version. I installed NVIDIA proprietary tested drivers from Ubuntu's software update center and everything seems to work and good, however my operating system and every program I use sometimes randomly freezes or stutters for a 1-2 seconds.
I think my system is in a good shape as I will share my specs. It has never been an issue on Windows (even though I hate Windows because of its disrespect to user privacy.) It feels like my computer is 10-15 years old. I really hope and ask for possible fixes or causes. Is it because of Ubuntu or is it because lack of some drivers?
Results of neofetch:
root@user-pc 
--------------- 
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: ABRA A5 V18.2 Standard 
Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic 
Uptime: 8 mins 
Packages: 1827 (dpkg), 34 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.21 
Resolution: 3072x1728(it should be 1080p?) 
DE: GNOME 46.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-11800H (16) @ GPU: Intel TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics]  
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile 
Memory: 3362MiB / 15734MiB 

